# Can't load into Ubuntu, fresh intall

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I did an install of Ubuntu recently on my newly built desktop PC, I have been stuck figuring this out for maybe 2 days now, I am a Ubuntu newbie but tried bunch of things, nothing worked!

When I restarted the computer after fresh install it displayed this error message:

```
"Error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'.
Entering rescue mode...
grub resuce>
```

I also tried loading "Try ubuntu" from live flash drive bootable ubuntu ISO installation, and installed boot-repair package and ran through the entire process. this is the link it generated, with the accompanying message:

```
Boot successfully repaired.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bbxzqK8HWf/

```
In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

You can now reboot your computer.


The boot files of [Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk).
```

This can be performed via tools such as gParted. 
Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Comment: Have you tried re-installing? Sometimes it just messes up and re-installing fixes it

Comment: I originally installed Ubuntu server first, tried that 2 times, and Ubuntu desktop I tried 2 times already I think